# how to write a distinct query in a Repository in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I want to implement a method in service where I call a repository method for getting distinct value of a field saved in an in-memory db based on another field.

This is my Controller layer.

```
@GetMapping(value="filters")
public List<String> getFilterId(){
    return filterService.getFilterIdByReportType(ReportType.TIMESHEET);
}
```

This is my Service layer.

```
public List<String> getFilterIdByReportType(ReportType reportType) {
    return filterRepository.findDistinctFiltersByReportType(ReportType.TIMESHEET);
}
```

This is my Repository layer.

```
@Repository
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select DISTINCT FILTER_ID from FILTERS where REPORT_TYPE IN (:reportType)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportType(ReportType reportType);
```

Tried using native query but upon hitting the api from controller it gave 500 internal server error.

PS: these are the columns in my table

```
ID,REPORT_TYPE,FILTER_ID,DISPLAY_VALUE,FILTER_TYPE,POSSIBLE_VALUES
1,A,organization,Organization,combo_box,ABC
2,A,country,Country,combo_box,XYZ
3,A,name,Name,combo_box,PQR
```

and the result should be like

FILTER_ID

organization
country
name

Comment: share the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `@Repository` over your interface as it already extends `JpaRepository`.

Second, there's a mistake in your `where` clause as `in` expects `reportType` to be an Iterable, so to make it work you should modify your method as

```java
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select distinct FILTER_ID from FILTERS where REPORT_TYPE in :reportTypes", nativeQuery = true)
  List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportTypes(Iterable<ReportType> reportTypes);
}
```

and pass e.g. a List into the method.

If however you query filters against a single `report_type` you should use plain `=` instead of `in`:

```java
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select distinct FILTER_ID from FILTERS where REPORT_TYPE = :reportType", nativeQuery = true)
  List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportType(ReportType reportType);
}
```

Basically, you don't even need native query here, the following would also work out for multiple report types:

```java
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select distinct f.filterId from Filters where reportType in :reportTypes")
  List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportTypes(Iterable<ReportType> reportTypes);
}
```

or for a single one

```java
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select distinct f.filterId from Filters where reportType = :reportType")
  List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportType(ReportType reportType);
}
```

P.S. If you are on Java 8 you need to specify `@Param`:

```java
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository<Filters, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select distinct f.filterId from Filters where reportType = :reportType")
  List<String> findDistinctFiltersByReportType(@Param("reportType") ReportType reportType);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey, thank you for your reply. Actually ReportType is of type Enum in the project so not sure if using Iterable<ReportType> reportTypes would be appropriate here.

Comment: @RuchiG then see example with `=`. Also if you don't need particular order of returned items you could change return type to `Set` in order to indicate you're returning unique elements.

Comment: @RuchiG if you are on Java 8 then you also need `@Param` over your argument

Comment: i'm using Java 11 actually

Comment: Then it's ok to have the param without `@Param` annotation